# I have previoulsy held an Italian passport (I currently hold a UK passport). Can I get one again?

Tags: uk-residents

I was born in the UK to Italian immigrant parents and held an Italian passport until my mid-twenties. At this point I decided to get a British passport. The Italian passport expired and I never bothered to renew it as I didn't think I would need two separate passports for the European Union. With Brexit looming, I am  now wondering if I can renew the Italian passport and also obtain one for my UK born children? My husband is English.  How do I go about obtaining a new Italian passport after such a long gap? I've been married since my Italian passport expired so don't even have the same name.

Comment: As long as you haven't renounced citizenship, you can renew your passport. However this is not a travel question so is likely to be closed.

Comment: You'll get better answers at [expats.stackexchange.com](http://expats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Relax, the actual Brexit is **at least** two years from now

Comment: @Crazydre two years is the timeline for a unilateral exit. If there is an agreement it can happen sooner.

Answer (score 3):

As Long as you can still prove you're an Italian citizen (for which purpose an expired Italian passport surely helps), you're perfectly eligible for an Italian passport and ID card